# Error in Room Database Compilation: "cannot find symbol" for DAO class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm encountering an issue during the compilation of my Android project that uses Room Database. The error messages indicate a problem with the generated AppDatabase_Impl class, specifically with the DAOvehiculo class. Here are the details:

Error Message:

`C:\Users\ramiro\Desktop\MiAuto\app\build\generated\ksp\debug\java\com\example\AppDatabase_Impl.java:35: error: cannot find symbol private volatile DAOvehiculo _dAOvehiculo; ^ symbol:   class DAOvehiculo location: class AppDatabase_Impl C:\Users\ramiro\Desktop\MiAuto\app\build\generated\ksp\debug\java\com\example\AppDatabase_Impl.java:157: error: cannot find symbol public DAOvehiculo VehiculoDao() { ^ symbol:   class DAOvehiculo location: class AppDatabase_Impl 2 errors`

Project Structure:

DAOvehiculo:

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.example.Vehiculo

@Dao
public interface DAOvehiculo {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM vehiculo")
    suspend fun obtenerVehiculos(): List<Vehiculo>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertarVehiculo(vehiculo: Vehiculo)
}
```

AppDatabase:

```
package com.example

import DAOvehiculo
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase

@Database(entities = [Vehiculo::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun VehiculoDao(): DAOvehiculo
}
```

Vehiculo:

```
package com.example

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "vehiculo")
data class Vehiculo(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int = 0,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "marca") val marca: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "modelo") val modelo: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tipo") val tipo: String?
)
```

Singleton:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.AppDatabase
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
import DAOvehiculo

class AppDatabaseSingleton private constructor(context: Context) {

    private val database: AppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(
        context.applicationContext,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        "vehiculos"
    ).build()

    // Access the generated DAO instance
    private val daoVehiculo: DAOvehiculo = database.VehiculoDao()

    // Method to get the DAO instance
    suspend fun getVehiculoDao(): DAOvehiculo {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            daoVehiculo
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabaseSingleton? = null

        suspend fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabaseSingleton {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = AppDatabaseSingleton(context)
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error File: AppDatabase_impl.java

```
package com.example;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.room.DatabaseConfiguration;
import androidx.room.InvalidationTracker;
import androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper;
import androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.Delegate;
import androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult;
import androidx.room.migration.AutoMigrationSpec;
import androidx.room.migration.Migration;
import androidx.room.util.DBUtil;
import androidx.room.util.TableInfo;
import androidx.room.util.TableInfo.Column;
import androidx.room.util.TableInfo.ForeignKey;
import androidx.room.util.TableInfo.Index;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration;
import java.lang.Class;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.SuppressWarnings;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;

@Generated("androidx.room.RoomProcessor")
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class AppDatabase_Impl extends AppDatabase {
  private volatile DAOvehiculo _dAOvehiculo;

  @Override
  protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(1) {
      @Override
      public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehiculo` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `marca` TEXT, `modelo` TEXT, `tipo` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, 'b4f3f95132a2f823a2eaf5a39bc336cf')");
      }

      @Override
      public void dropAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `vehiculo`");
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
          for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
            mCallbacks.get(_i).onDestructiveMigration(_db);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
          for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
            mCallbacks.get(_i).onCreate(_db);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onOpen(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        mDatabase = _db;
        internalInitInvalidationTracker(_db);
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
          for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
            mCallbacks.get(_i).onOpen(_db);
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPreMigrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        DBUtil.dropFtsSyncTriggers(_db);
      }

      @Override
      public void onPostMigrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
      }

      @Override
      public RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult onValidateSchema(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        final HashMap<String, TableInfo.Column> _columnsVehiculo = new HashMap<String, TableInfo.Column>(4);
        _columnsVehiculo.put("id", new TableInfo.Column("id", "INTEGER", true, 1, null, TableInfo.CREATED_FROM_ENTITY));
        _columnsVehiculo.put("marca", new TableInfo.Column("marca", "TEXT", false, 0, null, TableInfo.CREATED_FROM_ENTITY));
        _columnsVehiculo.put("modelo", new TableInfo.Column("modelo", "TEXT", false, 0, null, TableInfo.CREATED_FROM_ENTITY));
        _columnsVehiculo.put("tipo", new TableInfo.Column("tipo", "TEXT", false, 0, null, TableInfo.CREATED_FROM_ENTITY));
        final HashSet<TableInfo.ForeignKey> _foreignKeysVehiculo = new HashSet<TableInfo.ForeignKey>(0);
        final HashSet<TableInfo.Index> _indicesVehiculo = new HashSet<TableInfo.Index>(0);
        final TableInfo _infoVehiculo = new TableInfo("vehiculo", _columnsVehiculo, _foreignKeysVehiculo, _indicesVehiculo);
        final TableInfo _existingVehiculo = TableInfo.read(_db, "vehiculo");
        if (! _infoVehiculo.equals(_existingVehiculo)) {
          return new RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult(false, "vehiculo(com.example.Vehiculo).\n"
                  + " Expected:\n" + _infoVehiculo + "\n"
                  + " Found:\n" + _existingVehiculo);
        }
        return new RoomOpenHelper.ValidationResult(true, null);
      }
    }, "b4f3f95132a2f823a2eaf5a39bc336cf", "605958ae84981404c7a079ac7652acfb");
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration _sqliteConfig = SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Configuration.builder(configuration.context)
        .name(configuration.name)
        .callback(_openCallback)
        .build();
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper _helper = configuration.sqliteOpenHelperFactory.create(_sqliteConfig);
    return _helper;
  }

  @Override
  protected InvalidationTracker createInvalidationTracker() {
    final HashMap<String, String> _shadowTablesMap = new HashMap<String, String>(0);
    HashMap<String, Set<String>> _viewTables = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>(0);
    return new InvalidationTracker(this, _shadowTablesMap, _viewTables, "vehiculo");
  }

  @Override
  public void clearAllTables() {
    super.assertNotMainThread();
    final SupportSQLiteDatabase _db = super.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    try {
      super.beginTransaction();
      _db.execSQL("DELETE FROM `vehiculo`");
      super.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      super.endTransaction();
      _db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)").close();
      if (!_db.inTransaction()) {
        _db.execSQL("VACUUM");
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected Map<Class<?>, List<Class<?>>> getRequiredTypeConverters() {
    final HashMap<Class<?>, List<Class<?>>> _typeConvertersMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<Class<?>>>();
    _typeConvertersMap.put(DAOvehiculo.class, DAOvehiculo_Impl.getRequiredConverters());
    return _typeConvertersMap;
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Class<? extends AutoMigrationSpec>> getRequiredAutoMigrationSpecs() {
    final HashSet<Class<? extends AutoMigrationSpec>> _autoMigrationSpecsSet = new HashSet<Class<? extends AutoMigrationSpec>>();
    return _autoMigrationSpecsSet;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Migration> getAutoMigrations(
      @NonNull Map<Class<? extends AutoMigrationSpec>, AutoMigrationSpec> autoMigrationSpecsMap) {
    return Arrays.asList();
  }

  @Override
  public DAOvehiculo VehiculoDao() {
    if (_dAOvehiculo != null) {
      return _dAOvehiculo;
    } else {
      synchronized(this) {
        if(_dAOvehiculo == null) {
          _dAOvehiculo = new DAOvehiculo_Impl(this);
        }
        return _dAOvehiculo;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.miauto"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.miauto"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    val room_version = "2.5.0"
    ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")

    // optional - Kotlin Extensions and Coroutines support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version")

    // optional - RxJava3 support for Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-rxjava3:$room_version")

    // optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
    implementation("androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version")

    // optional - Test helpers
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version")

    // optional - Paging 3 Integration
    implementation("androidx.room:room-paging:$room_version")

    implementation("com.google.devtools.ksp:symbol-processing-api:1.9.21-1.0.15")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.3.0")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.9.1")
    implementation ("org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.7.5")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-common:2.6.1")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.8.0-RC")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to create ```getVehiculoDao``` instance. check out this blog :: https://medium.com/huawei-developers/room-database-with-kotlin-mvvm-architecture-477c3ad3c264

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that:

```
// Method to get the DAO instance
suspend fun getVehiculoDao(): DAOvehiculo {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        daoVehiculo
    }
}
```

Actually, you don't need that whole class, you can create companion object inside you AppDatabase:

```
companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase ? = null
    
    suspend fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
       return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
              INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                         AppDatabase::class.java,
                          "vehiculos").build()
              INSTANCE!! 
                }
            }
        }
```

And your abstract VehiculoDao() is public, you can use it

Comment: I delete the singleton and still got the same error, clearly that's not the problem.